# Using CUDA for a brute force attack. About memory allocation

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm writing a program that tries every combination of a 32 bit number, sees if it meets certain conditions and returns those that do. From the example programs I've been seeing the size of the array is always (No of elements * sizeof()).

This number seems way too big, and also most of the numbers will be rejected too so I don't need a 2^32 array. I know the number of results will be significantly less than 2^32 but I don't know exactly how many there will be either.

Also each thread will be looping as they try the numbers so it's possible that a thread has more than one positive result.

So how do I do the memory allocation and how do I store the accepted values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to try and allocate as much memory as you can or think you will need to store your kernel output, then use an atomically incremented counter to track the next free location in the output buffer where any given thread can store a result.

For example, if you define a helper structure something like this:

```
struct counter
{
    unsigned int * _val;

    __host__ __device__
    counter(unsigned int * value) : _val(value) {}; 

    __device__
    unsigned int next() {
       return atomicAdd(_val, 1);
    };
}
```

and then in host code do something like

```
unsigned int * array_index;
const unsigned int zero = 0;
cudaMalloc((void **)&array_index, sizeof(unsigned int*));
cudaMemcpy(array_index, &zero, sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
counter mycounter(array_index);
```

you have a zero initialised device memory counter which can be safely read and incremented in device code by repeatedly calling the `next()` method.

Within the kernel this looks like:

```
__global__ void kernel(Type * buffer, counter mycounter)
{
      // Calculate and find a match...
      buffer[mycounter.next()] = match;
}
```

[Strong caveat: all code written in browser, not compiled or tested, might set your GPU on fire, use at own risk]

Your kernel can then emit as many outputs per thread as fits well with your algorithm design. It would be prudent to expand the design pattern I have illustrated above to include bounds checking on the array. You should also note the total number of outputs which the kernel emitted can be retrieved like this:

```
unsigned int N;
cudaMemcpy(&N, array_index, sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

This solution will probably be the most useful when the output of the kernel is fairly "sparse", i.e. the number of outputs relative to the number of threads or the number of inputs is fairly small. If your problem is more "dense", i.e. the kernel will emit a lot of outputs relative to the number of threads, or inputs, then the atomic memory transactions might represent a significant performance penalty. In such a case, it might be better to have threads store into a "sparse" output buffer and use a stream compaction pass afterwards to eliminate the small number of empty entries from the kernel output buffer.

Comment: I don't suppose there's some kind of global variable that will be shared across all the spawned threads and I could just increment that instead?

Comment: @watisit: That is exactly what the code I gave does. If you have a global variable, whether statically or dynamically declared, you *must* use atomic increment operations for it to work. The class is just sugar to make life easier (and it  works with any type of memory which supports atomic memory transactions, like shared memory)